# Session expiration issue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have some issues with ASP.NET MVC session state which is not expiring after I implement the following piece of code and put the attributes over the methods.

```
public sealed class SessionActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void  OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        //Check if session is supported 
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        { 
            //Check if the session is new
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                //If it says it is a new session but an existing cookie exists
                //then it must have timed out
                string sessionCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]; 
                if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
                {
                    //Redirect to the login page
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index", true);
                    ctx.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the Redirection request is not executing and the Action which has SessionActionFilter Attribute executes. This method uses session variables which are expired and results in error.

Can anybody tell what I am missing?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: I'm curious to what exactly your using the session for?

Answer (score 0):

We are storing some data which is used in our views!! One more update I was able to run this piece of code which is now working fine. However, I am a bit skeptical about the use of cookies and need to transform this code to work for cookieless sessions also. How is this possible?